# Problems When Trying to display images from Parse using Swift

Tags: ios, image, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to display an image from parse using swift. This is my code:

```
var query = PFQuery(className: "Maps")
            query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("1234asdf3456") {
                (object: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if error == nil
                {
                    println(object)
                    var objectAsPF = object as PFObject!
                    let file = objectAsPF["imageFile"] as! PFFile
                    file.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
                        (imageData:NSData?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
                        if error == nil {
                            if let imageData = imageData {
                                let map:UIImage = UIImage(data: imageData)!
                                self.MapView.image = map
                                println("success")
                            }
                        }   
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    println(error)
                }
            }
```

I set a breakpoint at println("success") and i checked the variable values and everything is fine until i try to convert imageData to UIImage. Any tips?

Comment: What is the error and where are you trying to convert?

Comment: Remove this line 'if let imageData = imageData' and the { for that one.

Comment: There is no error the image simply doesn't appear on the screen. MapView is a image view and i try to convert the NSData to UIImage with UIImage(data: imageData). When i set a breakpoint in the code i see that the NSData is not nil, but the image is nil.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to retrieve images from parse then convert it from a PFFile to a UIImage...

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"Maps")
    
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
                (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                
                if error == nil {
                    // The find succeeded.
                    self.scored = objects!.count
                    // Do something with the found objects
                    if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                        for object in objects {
                            let userImageFile = object["imageFile"] as! PFFile
                            userImageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
                                (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                                if error == nil {
                                    if let imageData = imageData {
                                        let image = UIImage(data:imageData)
                                        
                                    if image != nil {
                                        self.imageArray.append(image!)
                                    }
                                    
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    // Log details of the failure
                    println("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")
                }
                
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    
                println("Finished Loading Image")
            }
```

Comment: Hi just a few questions about this code. What is the purpose of self.scored? Also what is the purpose of dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())

Comment: Also when I run this code I get a fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value