# Fatal error when trying to load images from parse using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am getting a fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value. I get this error after the code gets to self.imageArray.append(image!) from this code:

```
func retrieveImages()
    {
        var query = PFQuery(className: "Maps")
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil && objects != nil {
                let objects = objects as! [PFObject]
                for object in objects {
                    let imageFile = object["imageFile"] as! PFFile
                    imageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
                        (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                        if error == nil {
                            if imageData != nil {
                                let imageData:NSData! = imageData
                                let image = UIImage(data: imageData)
                                self.imageArray.append(image!)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I have checked each line of code and image does not become nil until i try to append it to the end of the imageArray.

Comment: That looks correct although I don't understand why you keep reassigning the variables, i.e., `let imageData:NSData! = imageData` I would say to change the end to this   if !error {
        let image = UIImage(data:imageData)
    }` Also try adding a nil check when you append.

Comment: I tried that and it still says that there was an error when unwrapping the optional value. When i set breakpoints i see that imageData is not nil and image is not nil, but when it hits the next line of code image becomes nil and i get an error.

Comment: See update answer you requested in the comments of this question...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30874394/problems-when-trying-to-display-images-from-parse-using-swift/30875017#30875017

Answer (score 0):

like previous mentioned, you are reassigning a lot of variables. Try you if-let statements on the optional variables like this:

```
func retrieveImages(){
var query = PFQuery(className: "Maps")
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) in
    if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] where error == nil {
        for object in objects {
            if let imageFile = object["imageFile"] as? PFFile {
                imageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) in
                    if let imageData = imageData, let image = UIImage(data: imageData) {
                        self.imageArray.append(image)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}